# What is so bad with throw :async

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asynchronous

I'm trying to find out how to create Rails API which could perform asynchronous responses. Many comments below the articles and the tutorials say something like:

> That `throw :async` really scares me
>
> `throw :async` makes me sad

So apparently using `throw :async` is considered as the bad practice but I haven't figured out why.

So I'll appreciate if anyone explain me why is it so bad, what are alternative approaches and so on.

Comment: `throw` (along with its accompanying `catch`) just throws an exception allowing an escape from multiple levels w/o dealing with `rescue`. Any time you're using `throw` as a flow control mechanism it's a red flag that something might be wrong--but there are times it's the best way to do it.

Comment: `Kernel#throw` throws objects, not exceptions. You can, of course, throw exceptions, since they are also objects, but throw is more general than that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

People are making comments like:

> That `throw :async` really scares me

because using `throw` is akin to writing a GOTO.

[image: XKCD GOTO]

This is a [big topic](http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/programming-with-reason-why-is-goto-bad/228200966) for discussion/debate, but the short answer is that `GOTO`s are generally frowned upon as "badly structured" code.

It is always possible to solve a programming problem without `GOTO`s, and seeing them in code *typically* indicates a hack that will cause issues down the line.

Here is an example of `throw` being used in ruby code:

```
def my_method
  catch(:escape) do
    outer_list.each do |item1|
      inner_list.each do |item2|
        throw :escape if item2 == "something"
      end
    end
    puts "something was not found"
    return
  end
  puts "something was found!"
end
```

The above `throw` is needed to break from a *nested* loop... But as you can hopefully see, there is a much simpler/cleaner way of writing the above code.

> A GOTO is a weak way out when you have weak design.

Perhaps the two most commonly used arguments against `GOTO`s are that code is more difficult to understand, and that there are more ways to arrive at a particular point in code.

This does not mean you should *never* use `throw` statements - but simply that they are generally discouraged, and you should think carefully about your design if you find yourself needing them.

Comment: wouldn't your example cause an infinite loop?

Comment: My example is totally contrived and doesn't really make sense -- the only point I wanted to make, really, was *"`throw` can be used for breaking out of a **nested** loop"*. But regardless... No, there's no infinite loop there.